Complex ReactiveUi Expression Depending On Two Properties
In my class I have two properties - BuildYear and LastRenovation. The business logic is such that the BuildingYear can not be greater than LastRenovation.If both properties were set(ex. BuildYear = 2024 and LastRenovation = 2025) and then BuildYear gets set to a greater value than LastRenovation (ex. 2026) I have to nullify LastRenovation and display an error message. I want to do all of this with ReactiveUI and place my logic in an observable. Due to the complexity of the business logic I am not able to achieve this so far because I can't figure out a way to nullify LastRenovation in my observable. I know that I can do this using WhenAnyValue and then use the Subscribe option and place a method(that execute the logic I want), but that's not the way if I want to use ReactiveUI.
Code:
 private int? _buildYear;
 public int? BuildYear
 {
     get => _buildYear;
     set
     {
         _ignoreLastRenovationYearSet = true;
         this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _buildYear, value);
         _ignoreLastRenovationYearSet = false;
     }
 }

 private int? _renovationYear;
 public int? RenovationYear
 {
     get => _renovationYear;
     set
     {
         if (_ignoreLastRenovationYearSet)
         {
             return;
         }

         this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _renovationYear, value);
     }
 }

showLastRenovationErrorMessage = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.BuildYear, x => x.RenovationYear, (buildingYear, renovationYear)
                => (buildingYear != null && renovationYear != null && buildingYear > renovationYear))
                .ToProperty(this, x => x.ShowLastRenovationErrorMessage);

